# Remove several types of event handlers for a specific element using .off()

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I have an element with multiple event handlers set different ways.  The code is long, legacy code, so I would like to change as little as possible.  However, I need to, at different times, remove ALL the event handlers at once.

Below is an example of the various handlers attached to the element:

```
$('#myElement').focus( function() {//Do Something} );
$('#myElement').keydown( function() {//Do Something} );
$('#myElement').submit( function() {//Do Something} );
$('#myElement').bind( function() {//Do Something} );
$('#myElement').click( function() {//Do Something} );
```

My question:  Can all of these be removed with one call of .off()?

```
$('#myElement').off();
```

Or do they all need to use .on to be removed with .off?

Comment: yes you can.`$('#myElement').off();` is perfectly valid syntax to remove all attached event for jquery 1.8+version

Comment: Tip for futur questions. Usually, when the question start by *"Can"*, you can answer it by trying it!

Comment: Another tip... [the jQuery documentation and the first result](http://api.jquery.com/off/) of [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=jquery+off&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) says exactly this:  _"Calling `.off()` with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [`off( events [, selector ] [, handler ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

> Remove an event handler.
>
> **events**
>
> Type: String
>
> One or **more space-separated event types** and optional namespaces, or just namespaces, such as > "click", "keydown.myPlugin", or ".myPlugin".

If you want to remove a list of specific handlers pass them via first parameter.

```
$("#myElement").off("keydown click focus submit")
```

If you want to remove all, `$("#myElement").off()` will remove *all* event handlers.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/muh1h77n/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes those can be turned off with `.off`

```
$("#myElement").off(); //unbinds everything
```